# Rails 7 Autoloading problem with active job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zeitwerk

I have an app directory in my Rails 7 App, app/beer, and in that folder a file named cool.rb with a defined method execute.

So in an ActiveJob **DrinkSudsJob** perform method I am calling a method execute from cool.rb as:

```
def perform
  Beer::Cool.execute
end
```

But my App blows up. Tells me **unitialized constant DrinkSudsJob::Beer**

Zeitwerk:check tells me everything is fine. What am I doing wrong here?

```
bin/rails r 'puts ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths'
/Users/sputz/Documents/Workspace/Apps/2022/fug/app/beer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `zeitwerk:check` passes and `app/beer` is in the autoload paths, then `app/beer/cool.rb` defines (and has to define) `Cool`, not `Beer::Cool`.

Comment: I agree. But in this App there was another module that defined an autoloaded whisky/cool.rb, and it was missing the method execute. So calling Cool.execute failed. So I tried Beer::Cool.execute, which failed. I now understand how to organize this better. 

I have /app/drinks/beer/cool.rb and that is different from /app/drink/whisky/cool.rb and so now I can reference Beer::Cool.execute() fine as opposed to Whisky::Cool.drink()

Comment: Exactly, that structure seems to match your use case .